# Running script that has sudo commands with sudoers

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, bash-scripting, sudoers

I wrote a script that helps clean up my downloads and anime, but it won't run without root.

So I tried adding it to /etc/sudoers (edited using techraf's suggestions):

```
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification


# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias FILEPERM_CMDS = /bin/chown, /bin/chmod

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
myUsernane ALL = NOPASSWD: /media/96e60511-62ca-48ba-bccc-9b365bfcc4e5/Programs/down.sh
myUsernane ALL = NOPASSWD: /media/96e60511-62ca-48ba-bccc-9b365bfcc4e5/Programs/rehamer.sh
myUsernane ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chown
myUsernane ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod
myUsernane ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: FILEPERM_CMDS

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

But this doesn't work...

Here's what's inside the script:

```
sudo chown -cR myUsername:users $downloads $anime >>"$default"logs/own.log 2>&1
echo owned
sudo chmod -cR 664 $anime >>"$default"logs/mod.log 2>&1
sudo chmod -cR 765 $downloads >>"$default"logs/mod.log 2>&1
sudo find $downloads $anime -type d -exec chmod a+x {} \; >>"$default"logs/mod.log 2>&1
echo moded
rm -vrf $downloads*.ignore >>"$default"logs/rm.log 2>&1
echo removed ignored files
```

If I leave sudo in the script it asks for my password once and does work. If I remove sudo from my script it runs without password promoting, but I still get the `Permissions denied` errors over and over. How can u fix this?

Answer (score 2):

By adding the following to `sudoers`:

```
myUsername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/down.sh
```

You have allowed `myUsername` to run `/path/to/down.sh` script with elevated privileges. This means you can issue the following command:

```
sudo /path/to/down.sh
```

It would be sufficient to run your whole script with elevated privileges and would not ask for a password. You don't need to put additional `sudo` for `chown` or `chmod` as these commands will inherit permissions from the script (but in this case `sudo chown` would run without problems, as `root` has permissions to run all commands without password prompt).

That's one possible way.

---

The other way...

You did not allow `myUsername` to run `chown` or `chmod` in `sudoers`. If you wanted to run script as a regular user and only allow certain commands to be run as `root`, you should specify all of them in `sudoers` for example:

```
myUsername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/chown
```

*your path to binaries might be different*

or specify command aliases:

```
Cmnd_Alias FILEPERM_CMDS = /usr/sbin/chown, /usr/sbin/chmod
myUsername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: FILEPERM_CMDS
```

This way you could use your script as is.

---

Finally you have specified your permissions under `# User alias specification`. This is only good practice advice, but this is not what this section is about. You should rather have it added to `# User privilege specification`.

Have a look at [sudoers examples](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers) for some common scenarios.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. My chown & chmod are in /bin.  Tried both settings that you gave (also put everything in the right location as per your suggestion), but still getting permission errors.

Comment: It's working if I change the b script back to `sudo chmod blah blah blah` but then asks me for the user password. The user isn't a sudoer but it does execute properly as root. How come it's still asking for a password even though the user didn't have root privs except on these commands?

Comment: Sorry, but commenting "tried everything and it doesn't work" is non-constructive. I have no idea what you do unless you write it.

Comment: By tried everything I put your commands into my sudoer file.

Comment: # Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias FILEPERM_CMDS = /bin/chown, /bin/chmod

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
myUsernane ALL = NOPASSWD: /media/96e60511-62ca-48ba-bccc-9b365bfcc4e5/Programs/down.sh
myUsernane ALL = NOPASSWD: /media/96e60511-62ca-48ba-bccc-9b365bfcc4e5/Programs/rehamer.sh
myUsernane ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chown
myUsernane ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod
myUsernane ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: FILEPERM_CMDS

Comment: Edited question using your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to have the script sudo itself. Add this to /etc/sudoers:

```
myUsername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/down.sh
```

Then add this at the beginning of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# If not already running as root, rerun via sudo
if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]; then
    exec sudo "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
    exit $? # in case something fails...
fi
```

As long as the filepath matches the entry in /etc/sudoers, it should be able to transparently rerun itself as root (so you can leave off the `sudo`s in the rest of the script). If it doesn't match for some reason, you'll get `sudo`'s password prompt.